# yaml include json in command

Tags: json, yaml

I am trying to add a command with json in a yaml (gitlab ci deployment)

```yaml
  script:
    - gradle buildZip
    - aws s3 cp build/distributions/converter-1.0.zip s3://xxx/converter/fan-converter-${CI_BUILD_REF}.zip
    - aws s3 put-object-tagging --bucket xxx --key converter/fan-converter-{$CI_BUILD_REF}.zip --tagging '{"TagSet": [{ "Key": "tmp", "Value": "1" }]}'
```

Seems that the yaml do not really like this part `--tagging '{"TagSet": [{ "Key": "tmp", "Value": "1" }]}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have a `:` in there followed by whitespace. This is YAML syntax for a mapping key. The surrounding `'` doesn't protect you because since it is inside a YAML scalar, it is parsed as content.

The best way to fix it is to use a block scalar, where YAML parses no special characters at all:

```yaml
script:
  - gradle buildZip
  - >-
    aws s3 cp build/distributions/converter-1.0.zip
    s3://xxx/converter/fan-converter-${CI_BUILD_REF}.zip
  - >-
    aws s3 put-object-tagging
    --bucket xxx
    --key converter/fan-converter-{$CI_BUILD_REF}.zip
    --tagging '{"TagSet": [{ "Key": "tmp", "Value": "1" }]}'
```

The `>` starts a *folded block scalar*, the following `-` prevents the final newline to be added. All lines are concatenated via space characters. Beware not to indent lines more than the first line; that would create a line break around that more indented line.

The scalar continues until it encounters content on a parent indentation level. I made the previous value another block scalar to demonstrate this.

You could also write everything in one line, but this seems more readable.